# Table limits in SQL Server 2005 Express

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, limits

I have a database table in SQL Server 2005 Express that takes in 2367 new rows each day, there is only 3 columns for each row. So in a year this will give around 800k of rows and in 10 years 8 million rows. Since I know that the company where I'm making this installation will not handle any database management/cleanup my question is will a SQL Server 2005 Express be able to handle this many rows in a single table? Are there any limits? I do know that there is something like 4gig of file size limit.

EDIT: Table setup

```
[RefId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[PointDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[PointValue] [decimal](10, 2) NOT NULL
```

note: SQL Server 2005 Express doesn't allow you to set up jobs.

Comment: Well, there's the free [SQL Scheduler](http://www.lazycoding.com/products.aspx) which works for SQL Server Express.....

Comment: How large are your rows?? If you have 3 INT columns - 8 million times 3 times 4 bytes each - that's a loooooong way from 4 GB is size.... also: SQL Server 2008 R2 Express has increased that limit to 10 GB - so that would be another way out, if really you had to....

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! The server itself is a windows 2003 server with and they will not leave 2005 sql express and they will not let me install SQL Sceduler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says limited by available storage. So it's likely you'll hit a bottleneck somewhere else first, like some MBA with Access doing select Count() from Table on with an external link to the live database.

Other maximums you might run into first.

[MSDN SQL 2005 Capacity Specicifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Other versions are available from the page as well, for those who have a need.

Answer (score 1):

The database size limit is [10Gb since SQL Server 2008 R2](http://rusanu.com/2010/04/28/sql-server-2008-r2-express-database-size-limit-10gb/). No matter what, an Express installation will still require maintenance (specially backups). You better think of something now.